# what does evaluate expansion means in intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, sh

I am writing a sh script in Intellij with two loops in there, in one loop

```
for i in {1..32}
do
some commands
done
```

intellij is marking the **{1..32}** as "evaluate expansion"

the other loop:

```
for text in {'fhv', 'green'}
do
commands
done
```

is not marking that error, what does the evaluate expansion means?

Answer (score 0):

Your second example, due to the space, is not a brace expansion. It is just two separate words, `{'fhv',` and `'green'}`. (Depending on the shell, it might be a syntax error.) Eliminate the space

```
for text in {'fhv','green'}
```

and you'll have a valid (though pointless) brace expansion expression.